# Sending .amr files to SIM900 over serial in c

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, uart, sim900

I'm trying to send `.amr` files from my desktop to a SIM900 GSM module over UART.

I'm using [teuniz's RS232 library](http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/).

I do the initialisation using AT commands and then read the file into a buffer and write it to the UART using the `RS232_SendByte()` library function byte-by-byte, but it doesn't seem to work.

I send the following AT commands:

```
AT+CFSINIT
AT+CFSWFILE=\"audio.amr\",0,6694,13000 # After which I get the CONNECT message from the SIM900 module
# Here's where I send the file
AT+CFSGFIS=\"audio.amr\"
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "rs232.h"


char *readFile(char *filename, int *size) {
  char *source = NULL;
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
  if (fp != NULL) {
    /* Go to the end of the file. */
    if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
      /* Get the size of the file. */
      long bufsize = ftell(fp);
      if (bufsize == -1) { return NULL; }

      /* Allocate our buffer to that size. */
      source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));
      if(!source) return NULL;

      /* Go back to the start of the file. */
      if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) { return NULL; }

      /* Read the entire file into memory. */
      size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), bufsize, fp);
      if ( ferror( fp ) != 0 ) {
        fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
        free(source);
        return NULL;
      } else {
        source[newLen++] = 0; /* Just to be safe. */
      }

      *size = bufsize;
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
  return source;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ret = 0, cport_nr = 2, bdrate=38400; 
  char data[2000] = {0};
  if(RS232_OpenComport(cport_nr, bdrate)) {
    printf("Can not open comport\n");
    ret = -1;
    goto END;
  }

  int size;
  unsigned char *filebuf = readFile("audio.amr", &size);
  if (!filebuf) { 
    ret = -1;
    goto END_1; 
  }

  /* Initialization */
  RS232_cputs(cport_nr, "AT");
  RS232_cputs(cport_nr, "AT+CFSINIT");
  sleep(1);
  RS232_cputs(cport_nr, "AT+CFSWFILE=\"audio.amr\",0,6694,13000");
  /* Wait for CONNECT */
  sleep(2);

  printf("Sending file of size: %d\n", size);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    putchar(filebuf[i]);
    RS232_SendByte(cport_nr, filebuf[i]);
  }
  free(filebuf);

  sleep(1);
  /* Check if file transferred right */
  RS232_cputs(cport_nr, "AT+CFSGFIS=\"audio.amr\"");

  END_1: 
  RS232_CloseComport(cport_nr);
  END: 
  return ret;
}
```

#### EDIT 1

Normally, the procedure to send a file to SIM900 using AT commands would be as documented [here](http://microchip.ua/simcom/SIM900x/AppNotes/SIM900%20Special%20AT%20commands%20about%20deal%20with%20the%20flash%20data.pdf):

1. `AT+CFSINIT` # Initialize flash; Response is OK
2. `AT+CFSWFILE=<filename>,<writeMode>,<fileSize>,<InputTime>` # Write file with these parameter; Response is `CONNECT`; So this is when I start sending the file
3. Here's where I send the file. If it worked and the sent file size matched the `<filesize>` sent in the above command, SIM900 must respond with OK, which it doesn't. :(
4. `AT+CFSGFIS=<filename>` # Gives the file size on flash. This gives me an error since the file didn't upload correctly.

This leads me to beleive there's something wrong with my program. I'm reading the file in binary mode. And the size reported is exacty the same as I specify in the `AT+CFSWFILE=<filename>,<writeMode>,<fileSize>,<InputTime>` command.

Comment: Be specific: what "doesn't seem to work"? What are the symptoms of the problem? What have you tried already in yours attempts to debug or fix this?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the problem description @barny.

Comment: In your code you hardcode the file size into the AT+CFWSFILE command. Have you added a print to confirm the file size that your program actually sends? Why not create the CFSWFILE command using the read file size?

Comment: That would be a good idea, but the file size reported in `printf("Sending file of size: %d\n", size);` is the same (i.e. 6694).

Comment: Sorry hadn't spotted that. Have you tried using a terminal program to send a very short file of e.g. 16 bytes (by you typing sixteen characters) and confirmed that this works? If this works, create an exact same file of sixteen bytes and get your program to send that.

Comment: Your cputs command is capable of transferring binary data?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try this and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: No... There's a `int RS232_SendBuf(int, char *, int);` for that. I have tried that as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry just seen that you are using sendbyte for the binary data. Errm, does cputs add a helpful \r\n on the end of strings it sends? Could this be messing things up if the module uses the \r and takes the \n as the first byte of the file?

Comment: There are several issues. (1)  teuniz's RS232 library uses non-blocking mode and does not use POSIX-compliant methods.  IOW that library is not truly portable.  (2) Your program is sending the AT commands without line termination.  So it's being received by the GSM module as one long incomprehensible command.  (3) After sending each AT command, your program needs to read the response from the GSM module.  Occasionally performing a **sleep()** is not an acceptable substitute for maintaining sychronization.  If you actually tried to read a response. the other issues would be more obvious.